# Inserting values into a hive table issue

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am attempting to insert values into a specific column in a hive table. The following query does not seem to work:

```
INSERT INTO table DQ_Rules_Status_Table_PROFILER (Load_TimeStamp) VALUES (2020-01-24) where Load_Ts rlike('Jan 24');
```

The error message received is as follows:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:86 missing EOF at 'where' near ')' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE DQ_Rules_Status_Table_PROFILER SET Load_TimeStamp = '2020-01-24' WHERE Load_Ts rlike('Jan 24');